# Unresolved referance "firebase" when trying to call TIMESTAMP, while all other services work

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I am trying to create a time stamp using the firebase server value.

In the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue) in says to use

`firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`

*edit: before I didn't realize I was looking at the JS documentation. I've relinked it to the Android ones though they don't seem to specify a format there. I'm still looking.

But it return `unresolved referance "firebase"`

I've looked at other similar question, and they offered other formats like `Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` and i've tried them but they don't work either and I think they're outdated.

My other firebase services are working just fine (Authorization, Database & Storage) so I can't understand why am I getting this error.

I am trying o achive that to create a simple timestamp the I will later, after pulled from the server, would convert to a nicer format with PrettyTime.

This is the part of the code the is giving me the error:

```
class NewQuestionActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_question)

        val questionTitle : EditText = findViewById(R.id.new_question_title)
        val questionDetails = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.new_question_details)
        val questionTags = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.new_question_tags)
        val questionButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.new_question_btn)


        questionButton.setOnClickListener {

            postQuestion(questionTitle.text.toString(), questionDetails.text.toString(), questionTags.text.toString(), firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP)
        }


    }


    private fun postQuestion(title : String, details : String, tags : String, timestamp : String) {

        val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/questions").push()

        val newQuestion = Question(title, details, tags, timestamp)

        ref.setValue(newQuestion)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.d("postQuestionActivity", "Saved question to Firebase Database")
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                Log.d("postQuestionActivity", "Failed to save question to database")
            }



    }



}
```

Comment: You've tagged this question "Kotlin", but you linked to documentation for JavaScript.  Maybe you'd like to take a stab at reworking this question so that everything lines up?

Comment: @DougStevenson sorry I'm new to firebase and missed my mistake. I've re linked to the correct one, but there doesn't seem to be a format provided there. I'm still looking.

Comment: It would also help if you state what you're trying to accomplish and show the code that's not working the way you expect.  You could be doing any number of things wrong, but it's impossible to tell so far.

Comment: I am trying to create a simple question board and want to mark posts using the PrettyTime library which requires a Date type. I've added that to the queston and also the code the fails

Comment: The code you're showing is using the JavaScript syntax for the timestamp token.  You will have to use the Java syntax.

Comment: @DougStevenson on the left panel in the link I've attached, there is documentation arranged by the different languages. There is none for Java/kotlin, only Android. My current link (updated after you've first told me I was reffering to the JS one, points to the Android documentations but doesn't suggest a syntax. If I try starting my call with FirebaseDatabase my only other option after that is getInstance and after that nothing that resembles ServerValue or timestamp, so not sure where to look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very odd a class start with lower case. I guess the most suitable approach is to allow the IDE to make the import for you, try with

```
ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
```